# Nginx, Suppressing/Masking default Error

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have written lua code and integrated in nginx to upload files into s3 bucket. If the upload fails or signature is malformed, i get an 403 Forbidden which is send to the client along with very verbose Error XML. 
I wanted to intercept/ return default error msg instead of the verbose error msg from s3 which reveals Access Key ID.

I tried adding snippet below but it has no effect what so ever:

```
error_page 403 /forbidden;

      location = /forbidden {
        internal;
        content_by_lua_block {
            local cjson = require "cjson"
            ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            ngx.status = 403
            ngx.say(cjson.encode({ status = "Forbidden. Check the Request" }))
            return ngx.exit(ngx.status)
        }
      }
```

When i see the reponse of curl cmd to upload, There are two status codes, 100 and then 403.

```
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Thu, 28 Sep 2017 04:26:31 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive >
```

How do i handle this to return default response for all 403 status code response.

Comment: You problem is ordering. In HTTP protocol status is sent first. So your `ngx.status = 403` should be before the `ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Note that while friendly errors are good, your AccessKeyId is not secret or sensitive.  There is nothing revealed in the "Signature Does Not Match" response that represents a security vulnerability.

Comment: @TarunLalwani i tried it, did not work...

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ya man, i hear you but it also reveals bucket details n what not.. AccessKeyID is not sensitive, but its still an low severity security issue... dont want it to be revealed.

Comment: Looking at it again, i don't think your block is even being called at all. Please post your nginx config for the proxy_pass